# Virtualbox shared folders - mounting failed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, shared-folders

I've installed Ubuntu 10.04 as a Virtualbox VM.  I'd like to make my entire C drive an always-enabled shared folder under ~ (/home/).  I've seen [this tutorial](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868) but I'm unsure of the differences between the commands they give.  After creating a new virtual folder called "C" under Virtualbox Settings -> Shared folders, I tried, inside `~`,

```
mkdir C
sudo mount -t vboxsf share ~/C
```

but I get

```
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error
```

What is the correct command to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://technologytales.com/2009/04/19/sbinmountvboxsf-mounting-failed-with-the-error-protocol-error/), the first argument after `vboxsf` (`share` in this case) should be the label you've given the folder in the Virtualbox Manager.  Since I called my folder "C" in the Virtualbox Manager, I was able to mount the folder with:

```
mkdir C
sudo mount -t vboxsf C ~/C
```

However, this method requires the drive to be remounted after start-up.  This [excellent post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868) suggests putting the command in the /etc/rc.local script, which is run on start-up:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 virtualbox_share_name /home/my_username/folder_name
```

The full path is required since it's running as root.

Comment: Worked for me using Ubuntu Server 14.04 on VirtualBox 5.0.20.

Answer (score 1):

In the past when I ran into a `protocol error` while mounting a VirtualBox share, I just went into the shared folders configuration in the VirtualBox UI, removed the share configuration that wasn't mounting properly and re-created it with exactly the same settings, then retried the mount and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup the share from the virtualbox interface in the Host OS. (I would not give myself write permission to C:. or for a short period and then remove it)
2. Install VirtualBox Additions in the guest OS.
3. Make your user (in the Guest OS) a member of the vboxsf group that has provileges setup correctly.

   > sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf bob
   >   (if your user is bob)

Depending on your settings as of 1) you'll get read/access from the "Computer" section showing drives, normally you should.